# writing tab separated values into a file

Tags: python

From a file, i have taken a line, split the line into 5 columns using `split()`. But i have to write those columns as tab separated values in an output file.

Lets say that i have `l[1], l[2], l[3], l[4], l[5]`...a total of 5 entries. How can i achieve this using python? And also, i am not able to write `l[1], l[2], l[3], l[4], l[5]` values to an output file.

I tried both these codes, both not working(i am using python 2.6):

code 1:

```
with open('output', 'w'):
   print l[1], l[2], l[3], l[4], l[5] > output
```

code 2:

```
with open('output', 'w') as outf:
   outf.write(l[1], l[2], l[3], l[4], l[5])
```

Comment: Take a look at the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) instead.

Comment: Use the `csv` module. That's what it's for. Edit: Pipped to the post, with a link and all. What he said.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use a parameter in the `with` statement representing the file you're writing to.  From there, use `.write()`.  This assumes that everything in `l` is a string, otherwise you'd have to wrap all of them with `str()`.

```
with open('output', 'w') as f:
    f.write(l[1] + "\t" + l[2] + "\t" + l[3] + "\t" + l[4] + "\t" + l[5] + "\n")
```

Alternatively, and more efficiently, you can use `.join()`:

```
with open('output', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\t'.join(l[1:]) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 6):

The `write()` method takes a string as its first argument (not a variable number of strings). Try this:

```
outf.write(l[1] + l[2] + l[3] + l[4] + l[5])
```

or better yet:

```
outf.write('\t'.join(l) + '\n')
```

Comment: You may want to add a newline here and there. :-P

Comment: `file.write()` doesn't automatically add a newline. Edit: This is happening a lot. Just a few seconds ahead each time.

Comment: +1 on the use of `join()` .. I like it much better than my own solution which also works, but is not nearly as slick :)

Answer (score 0):

```
outf.write('{0[1]}\t{0[2]}\t{0[3]}\t{0[4]}\t{0[4]}\n'.format(l))
```

will write the data to the file tab separated. Note that write doesn't automatically append a `\n`, so if you need it you'll have to supply it yourself.

Also, it's better to open the file using `with`:

```
with open('output', 'w') as outf:
   outf.write('{0[1]}\t{0[2]}\t{0[3]}\t{0[4]}\t{0[4]}\n'.format(l))
```

as this will automatically close your file for you when you are done or an exception is encountered.

Comment: @RafeKettler probably true, but I'm trying to use the new formatting way ... *it is functional and correct though*

Comment: which isn't useful in repetitive and simple cases like this, @Levon

Comment: @RafeKettler maybe you want to make the same identical point a 3rd time, I don't think I got it the first 2 times (even though I acknowledged your comment after the first one). You know, just to be sure.